# Change image being dropped into folder Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to change the image that is being dropped into a Windows folder during a drag & drop event in javascript. How would I achieve this/is there a better way to do this?

This is what I've tried so far with no luck.

```js
function drag(event) {
    var newImageUrl = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4n_urpJ9XpwOTdzBVbGvactwHrPagYQrTJPYjxfxLGkSyu7nJZVqRVGAeohnPgKMrnKE&usqp=CAU";
    var dragImg = document.createElement('img');
    dragImg.src = newImageUrl
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImg, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<img ondrag="drag(event)" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setDragImage()` method does change the dragged image that you see, however it does not actually change the dragged data (being the original image). Think of it as more of a *preview* of what's being dragged. Also the `setDragImage()` method seems to be used on the `dragstart` event, rather than the `drag` event.

And so you also will want to use the `setData()` method to change the dragged data/image as well. The `setData()` method has 2 parameters, ***format***, and ***data***. There are a number of different formats, but for images it is generally recommended that you use `text/uri-list` when your image is a URL. And because we are passing this as a text (the url of the image), we want to pass in the `src` of our image rather than the image object itself.

**Note:** my example is fundamentally the same as yours, but I try to avoid using inline event listeners so that has been changed.

```js
let dragImg = document.createElement('img')
dragImg.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4n_urpJ9XpwOTdzBVbGvactwHrPagYQrTJPYjxfxLGkSyu7nJZVqRVGAeohnPgKMrnKE&usqp=CAU"

document.querySelector("#testImage").addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImg, 0, 0)
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/uri-list", dragImg.src)
})
```

```html
<img id="testImage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

Another small thing to note is that the `setDragImage()` method will fallback to the default/original image if the new image either fails to load, or has not loaded yet. This means if you try to create the `img` element as soon as the `dragstart` event is triggered, the new image may not load in time and you will still see the original (google logo) image. But once the image is dropped, it will load the new image. This is fixed by creating the `img` element outside of the event listener to make sure it loads before the event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped clear a few things up. Although, it seems like the Twitter logo isn't being downloaded when I drop it into a Windows folder?